# How do I list unread message counts for Getstream chat users in Node?

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I am working with GetStream chat and want to check in the backend how many unread messages each user has. Then I can combine this information with other factors to send the users reminder emails.

I can see the number of unread messages for a single user in my React frontend like this:

`chatClient.user.unread_count`.

Here, `user` looks like this:

```
banned: false
channel_mutes: []
created_at: "2021-05-12T08:26:19.916648Z"
devices: []
id: "myusername"
image: "https://example.com/images/myusernameimage.png"
invisible: false
language: ""
last_active: "2021-07-15T03:41:01.684105658Z"
mutes: []
name: "Firstname Secondname"
online: true
role: "user"
roles: []
total_unread_count: 0
unread_channels: 0
unread_count: 0
updated_at: "2021-07-14T18:41:08.993427Z"
```

And `chatClient` is what I get from `StreamChat.getInstance(MY_REACT_APP_STREAM_KEY)`

However, this doesn't work in Node. For example, this gives `undefined`:

```
chatClient.queryUsers({ id: 'myuser' })
  .then((user) => console.log(user.unread_count))
```

Comment: What is the value of `user` object?

Comment: @Gajus I updated the question with this information

Answer (score 1):

Only connect (ws) sends unread counts. For server side (Node), they aren't sent.

You can connect your user as React front-end but beware it increases concurrent connection counts so affects billing.

A new endpoint will be added for server-side use-cases which doesn't create websocket connection.

Comment: Any status on this endpoint?

Comment: ETA is Q1 for new unread system